# How to call a function nested within within a promise from the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

This is my factory. I'm calling the promise from the factory, because I'm trying to keep my controllers as clean as possible, and the session information never really needs to be updated / put into $scope. But, since it's async, how would I call getNextEvent (another async function) from the controller, and still have it be able to referrence the var sessionId?

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

angular.module('csMgmtApp')
    .factory('agentFactory', ['$http', function($http){

        var result = {},
            data = {},
            access_token = result.access_token,
            baseURI = result.resource_server_base_uri;

        function startSession(startSessionPayload){
                access_token = result.access_token;
                baseURI = result.resource_server_base_uri;

            return $http({
                'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token, 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
                'data': startSessionPayload
            }).then(function(res){
                 data.sessionId = res.data.sessionId;
                console.log("sessionId", data.sessionId);


 Want to call from controller --> function getNextEvent(timeout) {
                    $.ajax({
                        //The baseURI variable is created by the result.base_server_base_uri
                        //which is returned when getting a token and should be used to create the URL Base.
                        'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions/' + data.sessionId + '/get-next-event?timeout=' + timeout,
                        'type': 'GET',
                        'headers': {
                            //Use access_token previously retrieved from inContact token service
                            'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token,
                            'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        },
                        'success': function (result) {
                            //Process success actions
                            //Note the scenarios listed below are only a 
                        });
 });

    return {startSession:startSession}
        }]);
})();
```

here's the controller:

```
csMgmtApp.controller('launchedController', ['$scope', '$http', '$document', '$resource', 'agentFactory', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $document, $resource, agentFactory, $timeout) {

$scope.agentStatePayload = {};
$scope.startSessionPayload = {
    'stationPhoneNumber': '2222222222',
    'inactivityTimeout': 0,
    'inactivityForceLogout': 'false'
};

$document.ready(function () {
    agentFactory.getToken();
});

agentFactory.startSession($scope.startSessionPayload);

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Agent Factory Part 1** Define the startSession function

```
angular.module('csMgmtApp')
    .factory('agentFactory', ['$http', function($http){
        var baseURI = "";         //from controller
        var accessToken = "";     //from controller
        var sessionId = "";       //from startSession POST
        var startResult = {};     //from startSession POST
        var startData = {};       //from startSession POST

        function startSession(startBaseURI, startAccessToken, startPayload){
            //save baseURI and accessToken
            baseURI = startBaseURI;
            accessToken = startAccessToken;

            var httpPromise = $http({
                'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken,
                            'content-Type': 'application/json'},
                'data': startPayload
            });

            var httpPromise2 = httpPromise.then( function(result) {
                 //save sessionId, result, data
                 sessionId = result.data.sessionId;
                 startResult = result;
                 startData = result.data;
                 //
                 return result;  //always return something
            });

            return httpPromise2; //always return something
        };
```

**Agent Factory Part 2** Define the getNextEvent function

```
    function getNextEvent(timeout) {
        var httpPromise = $http({
            //use previously saved sessionID
            'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions/' + 
                   sessionId + '/get-next-event?timeout=' + timeout,
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken,
                        'content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });
        return httpPromise; //always return something
    };

    //always return something
    return { "startSession": startSession,
             "getNextEvent": getNextEvent
           };
}]);
```

**Controller** Use those functions to **chain** promises

```
angular.module('csMgmtApp')
    .controller('launchedController', ['$scope','agentFactory',
                              function ($scope, agentFactory) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.baseURI = /* base URI here */ ;
    vm.accessToken = /* access token here */ ;
    vm.startPayload = {
        'stationPhoneNumber': '2222222222',
        'inactivityTimeout': 0,
        'inactivityForceLogout': 'false'
    };

    //get functions from agentFactory
    var startSession = agentFactory.startSession;
    var getNextEvent = agentFactory.getNextEvent;

    //Create start session promise
    var startSessionPromise = startSession(vm.baseURI,
                                           vm.accessToken,
                                           vm.startPayload);

    //Use startSessionPromise to create nextPromise
    var nextPromise = startSessionPromise.then( function (result) {
        vm.startData = result.data;
        vm.startDataReady = true;
        return getNextEvent(timeout); //call getNextEvent here
    });

    //Get data from nextPromise
    nextPromise.then( function (result) {
        vm.nextData = result.data;
        vm.nextDataReady = true;
    }) .catch ( function (error) {
        //process errors
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to return a promise from `startSession` that will resolve with the `sessionId`.  This would allow you to call `getNextevent` from anywhere, and have the main client be aware of the current session.

---

```
//factory 

function startSession(startSessionPayload) { 
    return $http({
      'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
      'method': 'POST',
      'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token, 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
      'data': startSessionPayload
    }).then(function(res){
      data.sessionId = res.data.sessionId;
      console.log("sessionId", data.sessionId);
      // should return promise (based on bluebird.js), not very
      // familiar with angular/jquery promises
      return data.sessionId;
    });
}
```

---

```
// Controller now gets sessionId and is responsible for calling next event

var sessionStartedPromise = agentFactory.startSession($scope.startSessionPayload);
sessionStartedPromise.then(function(sessionId) {
    getNextEvent(timeout, sessionId);
});
```

The above would make `getNextEvent` completely independent of the factory because it would take a sessionId.  I'm not sure of the specifics of factories in angular and how they are loaded across controllers, but this might make it so if you export `getNextEvent` it will still have access to `data` with the `sessionId`, not really sure though...

Comment: In your opinion, do you think this would be more clean than calling the original startSession promise in the controller, then passing the session Id from the controller, back to the factory for getNextEvent?  I'm at the point where I don't just want things to work, just trying to figure out best practices.